# Change img src depending on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you use `background` to set img.

You can change the img by class

```
<img class=".png" style="background: url('test.png');">

.png{
    background: url('test2.png');
}
```

However when use `src`, is it possible to change the img by class?

```
<img src="test.png">
```

I think it is possible to change `src` by javascript, but if I can sort the things by class it is better to handle.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this using HTML and some JavaScript (I'll use jQuery here since you tagged jQuery).

First you should add the class you want to target with JavaScript to the `img` elements that you want to change.

And then target them using jQuery and change their `src` attribute to whatever you want to change it to.

**HTML**

```
<img class="png" src="test.png">
```

**JavaScript**

```
// use jQuery to select all elements with the png class - and set the src attribute to...
jQuery('.png').attr('src', 'test2.png');
```

Comment: I choose this way. In conclusion, I cant change the `src` just changing case.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, background wouldn't change, because inline style have the highest priority)

Proof:

```css
.png{
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-image: url('another.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="png" style="background-image: url('https://gyazo.com/f850be7e9fc91aa2c8cb844603ea1e10.png');"></div>
```

You can set a fully transparent png image as src, and work with it's background:

```css
.set-bg {
  width: 320px; /* have to set exact sizes*/
  height: 320px;
  background-image: url('https://i.gyazo.com/fe48322c44d1c214ee8d9ba49876a0da.png');
}
```

```html
<img src="invis.png" class="set-bg">
```

Also, you can change (set) `src` with JavaScript. Usage:

```js
setSrcByClass("bubu", "https://gyazo.com/c708f879e56f725318fafca74b9cbe7f.png");

function setSrcByClass(className, src){
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll("." + className);
  for( let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ){
    elems[i].src = src; // src must be a full adress
    
   // or, if you want to set a relative adress...
   // elems[i].setAttribute('src', src);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="bubu">
<img class="bubu">
<img class="bubu">
```

Comment: Thank you I tried this way but using `background` is a bit different from using `src` (somwhow my image is not propery centered). but I really appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of the way:

```js
$("img[src='test.png'").attr("src","http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-FLnjwm6youQ/UUGhQei8KqI/AAAAAAAAAUE/nEl-5V5IcDw/s30-p/1.jpg");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="test.png">
```

```js
$("img[src='test.png'").attr("class","test_img");
```

```css
.test_img{padding:30px;background: #dae9bc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="test.png">
<img src="test.png">
```

*Sorry i can't understand your question fully that's why i wrote two snippets*

Comment: Thank you very much, this also works for me, but my ideal way is just changing class name to change the image file. but it turns out impossible without using `background`